# Basic JSON - issue with the bloody bracket

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

For a while now I've been trying to add Airtouch to HOmebridge and failing miserably.

[Current attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vBTr.png)

The original code is this

```json
"platforms": [
    {
        "platform": "Airtouch",
        "name": "Airtouch",
        "ip_address": "192.168.0.10",
        "ac_include_temps": false,
        "units": [
            {
                "manufacturer": "LG",
                "model": "B36AWY-7G6",
                "fan": ["AUTO", "QUIET", "LOW", "MEDIUM"]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What am I missing? Happy to find someone to be able to troubleshoot & fix :)

Validation error:

[Validation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCSnJ.png)

Comment: }
        ,{
            "platform": "Airtouch",
            "name": "Airtouch",
            "ip_address": "192.168.20.221",
            "ac_include_temps": false,
            "units": [
                    {
                            "manufacturer": "Mitsubishi",
                            "model": "B36AWY-7G6",
                            "fan": ["LOW", "MED", "HIGH", "POWERFUL"]
                    }
            ]
}

Comment: I suggest you either post you're complete JSON object or try validating your JSON using this online  [validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: Thank you, Alexander, how do I post it without credentials? Should I attach it as the file?

Comment: @alexanderdavide I added the picture to the original post. This is what it complains about after going through the check:

      {
         "platform":"Airtouch",
         "name":"Airtouch",
         "ip_address":"192.168.20.221",
         "ac_include_temps":false,
         "units":[
            {
               "manufacturer":"Mitsubishi",
               "model":"B36AWY-7G6",
               "fan":[
                  "LOW",
                  "MED",
                  "HIGH",
                  "POWERFUL"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]

Comment: If you can you upload the whole config file, I maybe able to help you

Comment: @user1239299 I can send it to you - - I don't seem to be able to add the entire script here :(

Comment: @Nikolay Shmakov send what you can

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, @user1239299 for sticking around, and @alexanderdavide for sharing the validator tool

I believe I figured out what the error was
I would love to know how to make it perfectly line up though:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY4C4.jpg)

At the moment it looks ugly. And when I move the lines of code to match the first picture, and upon saving the config, I get this. The last two brackets caused the issue :) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuytA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets do align with each other

[image]

Comment: Is it how it supposed to be? this is just that it looks odd and that I get some errors from the system  such as:  [11/08/2022, 12:40:26] [homebridge-airtouch4-platform-dp] This plugin generated a warning from the characteristic 'Target Position': characteristic value expected valid finite number and received "undefined" (undefined). See https://homebridge.io/w/JtMGR for more info.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update your question with a screenshot of your current setup?